# Can the comparison operators be used in select clause for column computing in SQL?

Tags: sql, odbc

Can the comparison operators (>, <, >=, <=, !=) be used in select clause for column computing in SQL? For example,

`SELECT column1, column2, column1 >= column2 AS "column3" FROM table`.

Seems only some of the databases support the comparison operators, such as MS Access. I'm using ODBC connect to different databases, one way I know is to use `"CASE...WHEN...THEN...ELSE"` clause instead. The question is, whether there's another way I can use comparison operators in select clause to compute new columns?

Another question is, if I want to use the new computed column ("column3" in the example) to filter some data in `WHERE` clause, how should the SQL look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right - this comparison syntax is not supported by all databases. But most popular open source databases: [MySQL](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73d48/2) (SQLFiddle link), [PostgreSQL](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/73d48/1) and [SQLite](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/73d48/3) all support it.

On [MSSQL](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/73d48/3) and [Oracle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/73d48/2), you should use

```
CASE a>b THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

as a workaround (and this will work for all databases mentioned before as well).

Regarding your question about using new column in WHERE clause: in general, you cannot do that, unless you wrap one more outer SELECT around your inner SELECT, and use another WHERE in outer SELECT.

Comment: The `CASE` syntax is ANSI SQL and works on all DBMS and should be preferred because it better documents the intention.

Comment: For using new column in `WHERE` clause, I just tried in oracle, seems I can directly duplicate the `CASE` clause in `WHERE` without wrapping it with an outer `SELECT`. Does it mean I can follow this way for most of the databases? Here's the SQL,

`SELECT avg(age) as avg_age, (case when (age>22) then 'true' else 'false' end) as retried FROM qmao_person group by (case when (age>22) then 'true' else 'false' end);`

Comment: You can certainly use whole `CASE WHEN ...` in `WHERE` on in `GROUP BY` without wrapping up in `SELECT` (but you will have to repeat whole expression). But you *cannot* give it a name (alias) as input expression and use that alias in `WHERE` or `GROUP BY`

Comment: Yes, seems it is a little stupid to repeat the expression in `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` than using nested `SELECT`. The question is in which way it is more efficient.

Comment: @AaronMao: it will be highly implementation-dependent. However, many vendors will optimize your query to the point that it will not really matter. It is common practice to convert sub-selects into joins, or to factor out common sub-expressions so they only evaluated once. For example, this is basically a requirement in `HAVING` clause - you must repeat seemingly expensive expression, even if it was aliased before. You best friend in these cases is `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I got the answer now. :)